# NetBeans + Maven, classpath

Tags: netbeans, maven, classpath

I've just started using Maven in NetBeans. However, I can't seem to figure out why `src/main/resources` is not included on the classpath when I run the project using `Run / Run Main Config`. From what I can see, only `/target/classes/` is included in the classpath, in addition to JARs from dependencies.

My impression was that `src/main/resources` is a standard location and should always be in the classpath, but this is not the case here. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the [Maven Resources plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/resources-mojo.html) will copy resource files from src/main/resources to target/classes, so they should still be available on the classpath.

Comment: yes, but the IDE build can do it too. not sure about netbeans, but IDEA's build/maven integration does it automatically...

Comment: @iangreen: While that's true, it's not usually a good idea to rely solely on IDE behavior to successfully build a project. Delegating this to a Maven plugin ensures that the project can be successfully built in CI or by any developer familiar with Maven, regardless of the other tools they may be using.

Comment: I am clueless as to how to use the above plugin in Netbeans...  can you give some directions?